# Search for a range of numbers in the title on Google News

Tags: google-news

I'm trying to find a range of numbers inside of titles in Google News.

I tried something like `intitle:4..25` but it only found results for which the exact string `425` appeared.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

My idea is that News is a way of slicing up Google's database that is incompatible with Google Search's Advanced search options. It is *either* a Title (from any indexed page) that contains a number in the range 4 to 25 *or* it is recent and features in News where search options are Headlines, Local, Sources etc (which options in turn do not feature in Google Search).